# Console text to file (java)

Tags: java

This might have already been asked before, but I haven't found a solution that quite fits my situation.

I have a program that repeatedly prints questions to the user and waits for user input (all in console). I *don't* clear the screen after each question/response, so the result is all of the questions and the user's answers just sitting there in the console.

Now my question is how do I take whatever is in the console at that current moment and save it into a text file? The way that my program is currently setup makes it illogical  to **individually** save all of my prints and the user's scanner inputs into a text file.

Is there a way to simply read whatever is in the console at that moment and save it into a text file?

Comment: just keep it in memory the moment you write it to the console. store the data in a List somewhere, and at choice write it to a file

Comment: You cannot write to the file from the program? The console is not a part of your Java program.

Comment: I swear I already saw this question recently but I can't find it...

Comment: @ShahanM Right. What I was trying to get around was not writing to the file for every single input and output I had currently written in the console. I got it solved though, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly calling the `System.out.print` methods, you can create your own `print` method that both outputs to the console and stores what was output into a buffer. Then, you can directly write the buffer to a file when necessary.

Alternatively, [`System.setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) can be used in conjunction with Apache Commons [`TeeOutputStream`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html).

Comment: Or replace stdout with the tee output stream of some sort.

Comment: Thanks! Never thought of making my own print method, but then again, I am pretty new to this. This works I believe :)